# Ajax XHR2 file upload access values in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have followed a very helpful tutorial online to upload a file through AJAX in a HTML form. 
Below is my HTML code then jQuery code.

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="upload" />
<br />
<progress id="prog" value="0" min="0" max="100"></progress>
```

jQuery

```
 $("#upload").on("click",function() {
    $("#myFile").upload("xhr2.php", function(success) {
    },$("#prog"));
});
```

How can I access the uploaded file in PHP to process the data and output any errors to the page?

**EDIT**

```
  // data is optional
    $.fn.upload = function(remote,data,successFn,progressFn) {
        // if we dont have post data, move it along
        if(typeof data != "object") {
            progressFn = successFn;
            successFn = data;
        }
        return this.each(function() {
            if($(this)[0].files[0]) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append($(this).attr("name"), $(this)[0].files[0]);

                // if we have post data too
                if(typeof data == "object") {
                    for(var i in data) {
                        formData.append(i,data[i]);
                    }
                }

                // do the ajax request
                $.ajax({
                    url: remote,
                    type: 'POST',
                    xhr: function() {
                        myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                        if(myXhr.upload && progressFn){
                            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',function(prog) {
                                var value = ~~((prog.loaded / prog.total) * 100);

                                // if we passed a progress function
                                if(progressFn && typeof progressFn == "function") {
                                    progressFn(prog,value);

                                // if we passed a progress element
                                } else if (progressFn) {
                                    $(progressFn).val(value);
                                }
                            }, false);
                        }
                        return myXhr;
                    },
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    complete : function(res) {
                        var json;
                        try {
                            json = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
                        } catch(e) {
                            json = res.responseText;
                        }
                        if(successFn) successFn(json);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Since we don't know what the `upload` method is (it isn't core jQuery), that's hard to say.

Comment: I will add the code for the `upload` function

Comment: I have tried that but when I try to echo a specific `$_FILES` value I get no result. eg `$_FILES['size']` returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be a tough job to do, since your form upload and the file upload are happening in different requests. This being said the only way you can reference your file is to have it be uploaded **before** the form data. There are different ways you can reference your file, through a session, pass it as an additional queryString parameter to your form, use databases ( which would be dull ), it's really up to you. The main problem is that they are in separate requests and you need to establish a connection between them. Good luck!